Name of a 80s or 90s American Kickboxing Movie
I doubt anyone will know the name of this movie but figured I'd give it a try.  I watched this movie when I was a kid and below is all I can remember.
The movie involved 3 (maybe 4) fighters that were captured.  This one guy beats all of the fighters except the last fighter which is female.  All I can remember about the fighters that fought this one guy is one of them is a black guy with dreads and the female fighter I believe is blonde.
Sorry for the poor description but if anyone remembers this movie and can share I'd appreciate it.
